# DAX Query - COUNTROWS statement using EARLIER

Tags: powerpivot, dax

I need to compare :

- `Contact Employee ID` to `EARLIER Contact Employee ID` (if they equal)
- and difference between `Opendate_Int` and `EARLIER Opendate_Int` (if less than or equal to six then count the row).

My query (`Data` is the name of the table in Power Pivot):

```
=COUNTROWS(FILTER('Data', EARLIER([Contact Employee ID]) = [Contact Employee ID] && EARLIER(Data[OpenDate_Int],[OpenDate_Int]-[OpenDate_Int]) <=6))+1
```

I am getting an error:

> "The second argument of function EARLIER must be an integer greater than zero."

Can you tell me where I am going wrong? Example (tables):

[image: This is a sample of the columns I am comparing]

Answer (score 1):

Your error is thrown due to this part of your measure:

```
EARLIER(Data[OpenDate_Int],[OpenDate_Int]-[OpenDate_Int])
```

The EARLIER function in dax takes two arguments. The first argument is mandatory and should be a column. The second argument is optional and should (if provided) be an integer greater than 0. 
In your statement the second argument is this:

```
[OpenDate_Int]-[OpenDate_Int]
```

which will always resolve to 0, because you are basically substracting a number from itself.

I assume that what you want to achieve is this:

```
=
COUNTROWS(
    FILTER(
        'Data', 
        EARLIER([Contact Employee ID]) = [Contact Employee ID] 
        && EARLIER([OpenDate_Int])-[OpenDate_Int]) <=6
    )
)+1
```

This part of the statement:

```
&& EARLIER([OpenDate_Int])-[OpenDate_Int]) <=6
```

will check whether the [OpenDate_Int] subtracted from the EARLIER [OpenDate_Int] is less than or equal to 6.